# How to remove a single element from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two string arrays in my typescript app:

```
public play: Array<string> = [];
public scene: Array<string> = ['gittare','saxsophone','drum'];
```

I want to push one element like `'gittare'` to `play` array and remove it from `scene` element:

```
this.play.push('gittare');
console.log(this.play);
this.scene.splice(this.scene.indexOf('gittare'));
console.log(this.scene);
```

I expect in the console, I see the `['saxsophone','drum']`, but it gives me `[]`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Read the documentation for [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Note carefully the description of what happens when the second parameter is omitted. Also, this has nothing to do with TypeScript. It's pure JavaScript as it has existed since the turn of the century.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is explained clearly in readily-available documentation.

Answer (score 1):

tell splice how many items to remove.

```
this.scene.splice(this.scene.indexOf('gittare'),1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update

```
this.scene.splice(this.scene.indexOf('gittare'));
```

to

```
this.scene.splice(this.scene.indexOf('gittare'), 1);
```